# How to write query to allocate and calculate funds in a loop

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I am trying to write a query( will convert into a procedure to store results in a table later) to allocate funds based on requirement. The query needs to calculate values from the previous record and then use that for calculation in next row.

I have two main tables, one that has master funds for each location. Second table has order details as to how much is needed and from what location.
I need to deduct the funds based on Amount required unless the funds reach 0, then move on to next order.

[![Master Table][1]][1]

[![Orders Table][2]][2]

[Results expected][3]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Are you pulling the expected results Country from the Order table then and not the master?  In master you have Camodia for C300 but in Orders you have Malaysia.  Also how do you calculate Amt Remaining?

Comment: Also how do you calculate Amt Remaining? Also how do you know which order to process the orders - should Order ID be descending (in which case the Sample Expected Results is in the wrong order?) Or is there another field to determine order?

Comment: Sorry for confusion I will update  the master table Combodia=Malaysia. Amount remaining =Amount-Funds any negative to be treated as 0. There is a date field I was using that to order the orders table. But assuming the orders table is by default sorted in order it has to be evaluated.

Comment: Can you add the date field to the sample orders table then? Also would you like all rows from the Master table to be shown or only show a row if there is a corresponding order for that office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you plan to order the rows so lets make some assumptions:

1) You join on Office

2) You process by the order ID in Ascending fashion (in which case you sample final result row order is incorrect)

3) Amt Remaining you never said so I'm just going to set that to 0 for now.

In this case the following query would work:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    select  o.ID, m.Country, m.Office, m.Funds, o.Amount, 
            row_number() over (PARTITION BY m.Office order by id) as rowid
    from Master m
    left outer join Orders o
        on (m.Office = o.Office)
)
select c.ID, c.Amount, c.Country, c.Office, p.[Funds],  
        p.[Funds] - sum(c.Amount) over (PARTITION BY c.Office ORDER BY c.id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as [Funds Remaining],
        0 as [Amt Remaining]
from CTE c
left outer join CTE p
    on (c.office = p.office AND p.rowid=1)
```

Example: [https://rextester.com/DGZEU1974](https://rextester.com/YJX79909)

Comment: Thanks so much Element Zero, this is the right start I needed. Will work on this to get my final results. Really Appreciate it.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if you are satisfied  and let me know if you have any other questions.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you somuch I had few other variables to be added to this and I tried your code and it worked just as expected. Ive alwyas admired how versatile CTE can be.Thank you so much for you help.